# XML conversion to Smarty .tpl file?

Tags: arrays, xml, foreach, task-parallel-library, smarty

I have following code in a file with extension .tpl (Smarty template)

```
{foreach from=$randomSites value=site}
    <a href="{$site|objurl:'siteDetails'}" title="{$site.siteTitle}" >
    <img alt="{$site.siteTitle}" src="{$site.imageSrc}" class="random_image" />
    </a> 
{/foreach}
```

It produce a list of sites with thumbnails..

Is it possible convert this code in a XML file with a simplexml class or similar?

I must convert in PHP code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.  First, you can use a Smarty template to create your XML, something like this:

```
<sites>
{foreach from=$randomSites value=site}
  <site>
    <url>{$site|objurl:'siteDetails'|escape:'url'}</url>
    <title>{$site.siteTitle|escape}</title>
    <image-url>{$site.imageSrc|escape:'url'}</image-url>
  </site>
{/foreach}
</sites>
```

Second, as you suggest, you can build your XML tree in a library like SimpleXML or DOM in memory, then serialize it to disk.  The benefit is that the library will prevent any XML markup errors; the disadvantage is that it will be harder for a non-XML-specialist to picture what the output will look like based on the library calls.

Comment: mmmm thanks the problem is that i need of adapt your code to carousel of flshow.net:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <slide_show>
        <options>
            <background>transparent</background>   <!-- #RRGGBB, transparent -->
        </options>
  
      <photo href="http://www.flshow.net/" target="_top">flower.jpg</photo>
      <photo href="http://www.flshow.net/" target="_top">flower.jpg</photo>
      <photo href="http://www.flshow.net/" target="_top">flower.jpg</photo>
   
      </slide_show>

Comment: It should work exactly the same way:

    <slide_show>
      <options>
        ...
      <options>
    {foreach from=$randomSites item=site}
      <photo>[[whatever]]</photo>
    {/foreach}
    </slide_show>